Detecting file import
I'm writing a blender script and I want to be able to detect when a mesh file like STL or OBJ is imported and then perform a series of operations on the imported objects. Ideally with a popup message before hand asking the user if they want to perform those operations or not.
Unfortunately I've been unable to find a solution that actually works except for creating my own importer with a WM operator where the user has to choose my custom importer which isn't intuitive and means I would have to make one for every file format.
Does anyone have a good way to detect if a mesh file has been imported and can also perform actions on those imported objects?
